# GDB exited unexpectedly when debugging with vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

I'm using vscode on Windows, and use mingw-w64 as compiler. my test code are as follows:

```
vector<string> words = {"SEND", "MORE"};
string result = "MONEY";
```

when I debug it, I can print 'words' and 'result' object correctly, but when I try to use subscript, something wrong occured:

```
print words[0]   // gdb: Could not find operator[].
```

and more seriously, when I try print string's subscript, gdb just crashed:

```
print result[0]
// ERROR: GDB exited unexpectedly with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). Debugging will now abort.
```

Those errors occurred samely whether debug with vscode or use gdb in cmd shell manually.
However, when I debug on linux platform using gdb, it works perfectly. That makes me confusing. I can't find if there's any bug in mingw, or maybe gdb doesn't support windows platform well. My g++ and gdb version are 8.1.0. I have tried some older version but all those have same problems. Is there any good solution, or shall I just give it up?

Comment: Error code 0xc0000005 means access violation

Answer (score 0):

Clean your path environment and PY_HOME.